# Отображение только одного товара на странице товаров WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В Desktop версии сайта у меня отображаются 3 товара в ряд. Мне бы хотелось чтобы в мобильной версии сайта отображался только один товар на каждой странице.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Comment: Вёрсткой...........

Answer (score 0):

в стилях прописать соответствующие media условия и подключить в теме в functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_styles' );
function add_custom_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 
      'custom_styles', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom_styles.css' 
    );
}
```